# what is the difference between 'Instant Pin Generation' and 'Credit Card ATM Pin'?

Tags: credit-card, india

I just got my HDFC credit card. When i logged into net banking site to create credit card pin, i found two options in the site, `Instant Pin Generation` and `Credit Card ATM Pin`. To create Credit Card ATM Pin, i needed to go to the HDFC ATM. So, i created pin using Instant Pin Generation. So, my question is, **are these two pins same?**

Comment: This probably is more of a hdfc bank specific question. no point in keeping the question. Please close it guys.. @Jayesh babu, you're better off contact hdfc help/customer care..

Comment: A search on "Instant PIN Generation" led right to [Your bank's site](https://www.bankbazaar.com/credit-card/hdfc-credit-card-pin.html).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's specific to this bank's process and easily answered via search.

Answer (score 3):

Instant Pin Generation code refer to the code for generating your new atm pin. Once it is used, the instant pin is changed.

No, you can not use your Instant Pin Generation code as your ATM pin code.

Comment: Can I use it for online purchase?

Comment: No, you can't. As Instant Pin Generation is only used for  creating you your ATM PIN for the first time. If you forgot your ATM PIN, you will get new Instant Pin Generation code.

Comment: @JayeshBabu if you got the solution from my answer please mark it as accepted, so that other users can be more confident for it, else you have doubt, don't be shy of asking...

Comment: No! It isn't the same it's totally different.  2 Ways to do this:

Answer (score 1):

No! It isn't the same it's totally different. 2 Ways to do this:

A. Through ATM

Call PhoneBanking to get the OTP (One Time Password) on your registered mobile number for
PIN generation at the ATM

Insert your credit card at the HDFC Bank ATM and on the language selection screen, choose
" Create new ATM PIN using OTP " option

Enter OTP received on your mobile

Enter your registered mobile number

Set your own 4 digit  PIN

OR

B. Through NetBanking

Login to NetBanking with your Customer ID and IPIN, click on the Credit Cards tab

Click the "Credit Card ATM PIN" option, select your Credit Card from the drop-down menu, and click on Continue.

Please Confirm the transaction, a message will be displayed to you on successful completion.

Your new Credit Card PIN will be delivered to your mailing address registered with the Bank